# removing multiple line html code at top and bottom and not in middle of two string 'hello' by preg_replace in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, regexp-replace

```
$data = '<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p> 
<p>hello</p> 
<ul>
 <li>&nbsp;</li>
 <li>&nbsp;</li>
</ul> 
<p>hello</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>';

$regex = preg_replace('/^((<[a-z]+>)(&nbsp;)(<\/[a-z]+>))/','',$data);
$regex = preg_replace('/((<[a-z]+>)(&nbsp;)(<\/[a-z]+>))$/','',$regex);
echo $regex;
```

> i am able to remove only single line of code at top and bottom, while the next line i can't able to remove.even i have tried this code also

```
$regex = preg_replace('/^((<[a-z]+>)(&nbsp;)(<\/[a-z]+>))*/','',$data);
$regex = preg_replace('/((<[a-z]+>)(&nbsp;)(<\/[a-z]+>))*$/','',$regex);
echo $regex;
```

my exact output want to be like this

```
<p>hello</p>
<ul>
<li>&nbsp;</li>
<li>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
<p>hello</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

use str_replace , hope its work

```
$regex = str_replace("<p>&nbsp;</p>",'',$data);
```